# Error when login to joomla

Tags: joomla

When trying to log in to my joomla site or admin back end I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::onAuthenticate() in /www/110mb.com/c/r/s/n/_/_/_/_/crsn/htdocs/libraries/joomla/user/authentication.php on line 121
```

Anyone know how I can sort this out thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that, you haven't even a single plugin enabled for user authentication.
There must be at-least one plugin enabled for user authentication. Option you have in admin panel under plugins tab: joomla, ldap and gmail. Enable the joomla plugin and try login.

But i think you will not be able to login in your admin panel also, as no plugin is activated for user authentication if i am on the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think one of your active authentication plugins is missing the onAuthenticate() method. When you login Joomla goes through all of your active authentication plugins executing onAuthenticate() . Look in the backend under Extensions -> Plugin Manager. See which authentication plugins are active. Then look in /plugins/authentication directory for the plugins being used and see if the onAuthenticate() is missing from any of them.

Comment: He says he cannot access the backend ... he would have to do it through the database using phpmyadmin for example to enable the plugin.